# Disable confirm parameters for transactions

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, ledger-nano-s

I'm trying to call a smart contract method with .send passing arrays of addresses with web3js and ledger nano. When i call the method ask me an endless list of confirms parameters ( not very clear what it is also) and the confirms are growing with the array size. How I can DISABLE it? I played with the settings but no success at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-install the ethereum applicaton. Probably the firmware was updated with some setting changes and the application need to be re installed to be up to date.